# Check if the .msg file has any attachments

Tags: vba, outlook

I have a folder with thousands of .msg files. My requirement is to check whether the .msg files contain an attachment.

I have the below VBA code which downloads the attachments from .msg files but I just need to check the attachment's existence.

```vb
Public Sub Extract_Attachments_From_Outlook_Msg_Files()

    Dim outApp As Object
    Dim outEmail As Object
    Dim outAttachment As Object
    Dim msgFiles As String, sourceFolder As String, saveInFolder As String
    Dim fileName As String
    
    msgFiles = ""       'CHANGE - folder location and filespec of .msg files
    saveInFolder = ""         'CHANGE - folder where extracted attachments are saved
    
    If Right(saveInFolder, 1) <> "\" Then saveInFolder = saveInFolder & "\"
    sourceFolder = Left(msgFiles, InStrRev(msgFiles, "\"))
    
    On Error Resume Next
    Set outApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
    If outApp Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Outlook is not open"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    fileName = Dir(msgFiles)
    While fileName <> vbNullString
        
        'Open .msg file in Outlook 2003
        'Set outEmail = outApp.CreateItemFromTemplate(sourceFolder & fileName)
        
        'Open .msg file in Outlook 2007+
        Set outEmail = outApp.Session.OpenSharedItem(sourceFolder & fileName)
        
        For Each outAttachment In outEmail.Attachments
            outAttachment.SaveAsFile saveInFolder & outAttachment.fileName
        Next
    
        fileName = Dir
        
    Wend
    
End Sub
```

Comment: You can filter your folder to look for all emails with attachments by using ``hasattachments:yes`` in the search box. By using VBA, what do you want to do? Count the total of attachments?

Answer (score 0):

Outlook Object Model won't let you access embedded message attachments unless you save the attachment first (`Attachment.SaveAsFile`) and then reopen the MSG file using `Namespace.OpenSharedItem`.

If using [Redemption](https://www.dimastr.com/redemption) is an option (I am its author), you can use [RDOSession](https://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdosession.htm).`GetMessageFromMsgFile` (return [RDOMail](https://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOMail.htm) object) to open an MSG file, but there is no need to save the embedded message attachments - [RDOAttachment](https://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOAttachment.htm).`EmbeddedMsg` property returns the message attachment as [RDOMail](https://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOMail.htm) object.